# Is using a different user to elevate considered better security in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, security, administrator, uac

In my organisation very few of us still have local administrator privileges on our user account (lets call it user A) in Windows 10. When ever we are doing something which requires administrative privileges the UAC pops up and we can enter our user A credentials.

The IT department wants to withdraw our local administrator privileges from our user account A and instead provide us with a different user account B with more privileges. We are then supposed to work using our normal user account A and when we need local administrator privileges and the UAC pops up, we can use our second account B to elevate.

I have no idea of how Windows 10 works behind the curtains, but I somehow wonder if using two different accounts are more secure than just using one. 
Further more I fear that by elevating using user B its settings could interfere with my normal user A's settings instead of just using user B to verify that user A is allowed to do something requiring more privileges.

**So is this more secure or is it just another *security-by-obscurity* measure?**

Comment: I do love constructive down-votes - it means I have a chance to change something :)